# Apply function to content of a CSV file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, csv

I'm currently working on a batch file which is giving me a hard time.
I have a generated .CSV file that contains a header and two columns. The file also happens to be encoded as ASCII (discovering this was a real revelation!) The second column contains a list of text files which I need to read and apply a function to each of the entries contained in them.

I thought of using copy or type >> to merge the files together into a single one that would be easier to parse but am having a hard time reading the content of the csv and using the content...

So far I'm using

```
for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in ("%temp%\list.txt") do echo %%b>>"%temp%\newfile.txt"
```

but it's not working...(all I get is an empty file) and I can't seem to figure out what to do next to apply a function to all the files listed so I can then process their combined content. I've been struggling with this for two days and am starting to get annoyed by what seems simple yet I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the content of my CSV file

> Client number,Client name
>   44456,James Bond
>   33356,Doctor Evil

And I have a folder containing files named James Bond.txt, Mister Rogers.txt, Chief Bob,txt and Doctor Evil.txt which contain the client information.
So, I want to is put together only the required names as dictated by the CSV file and then print out the complete list of everything in one go.

Hoping this clarifies things (I know, it's hard to explain)

EDIT
I tried the proposed piece of code and it still doesn't work...All I get is an empty file... but for some reason I think it looks promising.

Comment: You should show a sample of your csv file, if necessary neutralized. Otherwise it's difficult to give any help. Maybe you should use `tokens=1*`to get the remainder of the line into `%%b`

Comment: ***"but it's not working."*** is worthless information - If you want help, you must describe how it is failing. What result do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the `Client name` columns has equally named files in the folder with `.txt` extension, the following batch should do.

```
:: Q:\TEST\2017-05\25\DEMO\SU_1212933.cmd
@Echo off
For %%A in (".\folder") Do Set "folder=%%~fA"
( for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (
   ".\list.csv"
  ) do If Exist "%folder%\%%b.txt" Type "%folder%\%%b.txt"  
) >".\Report.txt"
```

To demonstrate this is my test environment

```
> tree . /F
Q:\TEST\2017-05\25\DEMO
│   SU_1212933.cmd
│   list.csv
│   Report.txt
│
└───folder
        James Bond.txt
        Doctor Evil.txt
```

the content of the two txt files in `folder`

```
> type folder\*.txt

folder\James Bond.txt

#################################################
## this is file "James Bond.txt" in folder     ##
#################################################

folder\Doctor Evil.txt

#################################################
## this is file "Doctor Evil.txt" in folder    ##
#################################################
```

After running the batch the file report.txt contains:

```
> type Report.txt
#################################################
## this is file "James Bond.txt" in folder     ##
#################################################
#################################################
## this is file "Doctor Evil.txt" in folder    ##
#################################################
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work. After much work I discovered that it fails at the IF EXIST part of the sequence. But the first part works fine so I might end-up doing things in two steps. Not elegant like I would like it to be but if it works...

Comment: Changed my answer to better demonstrate what the batch does. Maybe you didn't adapt the variable folder properly.

Comment: Definitely looks like it can't find the files on mine... I'll set-up a few folders like on your machine and see what needs fixing for my application.    Thank you.

Comment: Well as it works in the test environment., there have to be differences in your real environment. To debug run the batch in an open cmd window and set echo on temporarily to see errors

Comment: OK! I think I finally figured out why it doesn't work on my machine! I got a hunch last night that the CSV file possibly wasnt properly encoded and when I checked it out with notepad++ I discovered it was encoded ASCII...

Comment: @McDonald's While I doubt the path is the reason I changed the Set command to a for which resolves the relative path to an absolut one.